# discord.py - Not Returning Changed Permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I wanted my bot to print the permissions that were added and removed but my bot is not returning anything even if I changed the permissions

Here is my code:

```
async def on_server_role_update(before, after):
    list_a = []
    list_b = []
    list_a.append(str([p[0] for p in before.permissions]))
    list_b.append(str([p[0] for p in after.permissions]))
    dif_add = set(list_b).difference(list_a)
    dif_rem = set(list_a).difference(list_b)
    print("Added Permissons: " + ", ".join(dif_add))
    print("Removed Permissons: " + ", ".join(dif_rem))
```

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?  Does the code your bot actually uses have the `@bot.event` decorator?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the updated discord py it's not `on_server_role_update` but `on_guild_role_update`, old version is not supported anymore so I would advise you to update.

Second, try printing `list_a` and `list_b`  after they are set, you'll see that you only get a list of all permission names: `['add_reactions', 'administrator', 'attach_files', 'ban_members', ....` how would you compare that?

Also you're missing quite crucial statement:

```
if before.permissions != after.permissions:
```

You need that because `on_server_role_update` aka `on_guild_role_update` will trigger for multiple events like name change, description change, mentionable change, position change, color change etc

So for a nice clean code:

```
if before.permissions != after.permissions:
        diff = list(set(after.permissions).difference(set(before.permissions)))
        # diff will be a list which has changed roles and their state AFTER the change, example:
        # [('manage_channels', True), ('view_audit_log', True), ('manage_roles', True), ('manage_guild', False)]
        for changed_perm in diff:
            print(f"Changed role permission {changed_perm[0]} to {changed_perm[1]}")
```

Example output:

```
Changed role permission manage_channels to True
Changed role permission view_audit_log to True
Changed role permission manage_roles to True
Changed role permission manage_guild to False
```